# Incorrect Magento 2 layouts override behavior

Tags: magento, layout, magento2

1. Installed clear magento 2.3.2
2. Created simple custom theme which contain (`theme.xml`, `registration.php` and `CustomTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml`).
3. Also I created a simple extension which add a custom field to customer accout create form (This extension also use `customer_account_create.xml`).

```
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
       <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Test" name="test"
              template="CompanyName_ModuleName::form/test.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

After that I got strange behavior:
If my `CustomTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml` as is like original file from core, non-standard field is added to the form without problems from my custom extension.

But if I will modify my file `CustomTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml` (for example I just added this string to remove minicart: `).
My non-standard field does not apply to the form

Everything looks as if I modify the layout for my needs in custom theme (delete some elements from the registration page), then all other custom extension that use this layout or reference to this layout will stop working.

Comment: I figured out this
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

I think you need to read a little more the concepts and process of development of your own custom theme before doing any big modifications, at the end you will have a really bad outcome and not sustainable code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this issue.
Me helped this sections of the documentation
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html